# Working with MDS Studio and Plazmic CDK

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I want to know how feasible/flexible is developing rich UI based applications with MDS studio and Plazmic CDK?

Or any other good GUI development tool is available for Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

Talking about Plazmic CDK - you can use it to create Blackberry themes or media content (animation, images etc).
[BlackBerry Theme Builder http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1456/bbthemebuilder.gif](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1456/bbthemebuilder.gif)

> What can you do with Theme Builder?
>   Some of its main features allow you
>   to:
>
> - Customize the BlackBerry application icons
> - Change the Home screen banner image and icon/indicator colors
> - Create your own buttons
> - Customize the look of dialog and pop up screens
> - Customize an idle screen
> - Customize the look of menus and lists
> - Customize the phone application screens
> - Customize fonts used on the BlackBerry device

[bb dev journal - Just Theme It!](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1456/bbthemebuilder.gif)
[BlackBerry Themes & Animated Graphics](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/sep_2006/theme.jsp)
[How To Create Your Own Personal Blackberry Themes by BrileyKenney](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/themes/)